# How to read all content in some pdf files except the tables inside them?

Tags: python, pdf

I want to read pdf files using python but while reading I don't want to include the tables within a pdf file. I just want every other content except those tables.

I have tried libraries like `PyPDF2` and `Tabula` but I just found the way to extract tables or read the content including table.

I also don't want to create a new file and appending pages into it. To be precise in pythonic way, all content should be in a format of `list` of `strings` except the content of tables.

Answer (score 0):

Recently tried this deep-learning technology enabled document text extractor tool (this is actually OCR tool by Amazon).
This gives more accurate results when it comes to extracting text from PDF or Image file.

For quick info refer;
https://aws.amazon.com/textract/features/

For examples and python SDK installation refer below;
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/getting-started.html

There are 2 functions to extract text from PDF files, contents as list of strings and also as in the form of Table/Forms/KeyValues format.